# Magmi authorization after install

Tags: magento, magmi

I use magmi 0.7.23-git, and Magento Enterprise 1.14.2.1.

When I install Magmi and try to access /magmi/web/magmi.php I see Apache's plain text authorization request. "magmi"/"magmi" and magento login credentials don't work.

How I can solve that problem?

Comment: @mike please check here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766183/you-must-be-logged-in-to-use-magmi?noredirect=1#comment61110286_36766183) if i use "magmi" for 1st time , i am getting error : `You must be logged in to use Magmi`

Answer (score 11):

if you just installed magmi and your getting "You must be logged in to use Magmi" error message. Try login in with "magmi" for both username and password.
on Magmi github page it states

> ## Authentication
>
> Following previous issues with the mis-use of Magmi in an insecure way, Magmi now contains built-in authentication.
>   Once you have provided DB details and Magmi can connect to the DB, you will need to login using a set of Magento admin credentials to use Magmi. If Magmi has not yet been configured to connect, then the username and password are both 'magmi'

https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git#authentication

Comment: please check here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766183/you-must-be-logged-in-to-use-magmi?noredirect=1#comment61110286_36766183) if i use "magmi" for 1st time , i am getting error : `You must be logged in to use Magmi`

Answer (score 7):

Check the file magmi/inc/magmi_auth.php line 35.
Magmi by default consider username:`magmi` and password: `magmi`.

I entered this and they are working for me.

Also magmi checks your connection with database, so it will also consider the credentials of your admin panel

If you did not wants to get authenticated then you have to comment out $auth->autheticate(); in security.php

Comment: also check admin_user  table

Answer (score 0):

What does does the page say if you fail authentication?  If the message isn't

> You must be logged in to use Magmi

then the basic auth isn't coming from Magmi.  Some hosts have taken to restricting access to folders named Magmi due to a significant number of store owners installing magmi and failing to restrict access, thus leading to a number of breaches.

If you find that the message is not coming from Magmi, check your vhost for a `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` node followed by some form of Magmi.

If you find that the message is in fact coming from Magmi, you can temporarily disable the authentication procedure by commenting out the following line: https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/blob/b57a10dab936986f484f191153e0524617ae0692/magmi/web/security.php#L7

Comment: @mike please check here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766183/you-must-be-logged-in-to-use-magmi?noredirect=1#comment61110286_36766183) if i use "magmi" for 1st time , i am getting error : `You must be logged in to use Magmi`

Answer (score 0):

Found out after a few minutes that Magmi requires a configuration file to be filled up with your Magento database information found under: magmi/conf/magmi.ini.default

Just remove .default and fill in your information.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same authentication problem. The file magmi_auth.php validation pass function needs a patch. This version of magmi resolved my problem because the patch has been already added. Here is the link: https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2