# You must be logged in to use Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

i have installed magmi_full_0.7.22 from git master : https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git#authentication

when i am trying to login for that first time, i am getting error :

```
You must be logged in to use Magmi
```

i used "magmi" for username and password, but still its not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming - in fact you didn't even ask a question. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for commenting on my post. if we post there also they will close as off-top , you can check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61688/magmi-installation-localhost)

Comment: Then perhaps on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: hi, i appreciate your concern regarding stackoverflow  community clean .

mostly this is new version magmi problem only, if i get this is server problem, surely i will delete here and post there.

Comment: But it's not a programming issue so it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using the most up to date version so unless it's changed you need your database username and password, not your magento admin.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your magento store's admin penal username and password.

Comment: for this version - `magmi_full_0.7.19a` , it didt asked any username , password and all. but for this version : `magmi_full_0.7.22` its asking.

Comment: can you give me link to download "image attributes processor" ?

Comment: I check your github magmi which is you used.  and found that you have already image attributes processor in it, please check your magmi i am sure it is there.

Comment: is there configuration i have to do in magmi web page for uploading images.

Comment: Yes in configuration set in Image search path=>media/import,  Image import mode=>Keep existing images,  Assign only existing images=>No,

Comment: you not add "/" before image name in your csv file, please image name should be "/image1.jpg" in csv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109868/discussion-between-rohit-savaliya-and-spylh9999ggr).

Answer (score 1):

The default username and password is:

```
username: magmi     
password: magmi
```

After login, you can configure Magmi with your database credentials. After that, you will be able to login with your Magento admin username and password.

https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git#authentication